# why this simple jquery code not working?

Tags: jquery, toggle

I'm trying to display different data based on the click of different `th` elements of a table. I'm using jQuery 1.7

But I dont know why this is not working??

what i want is that when user click on specific `th` then the table which have the class of that `th` id shoud display and other tables must be hidden at that time..

Here is my fiddle and  please helps me out.

#### http://jsfiddle.net/78UKh/3/

**Note :** Please dont suggest other ways around, because I have written a lot of jquery code already in that page.

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Instead of using:

```
$('#detailsDiv > table').hasClass(''+thisvalue +'').show();
```

Use a filter:

```
$('#detailsDiv > table').filter('.'+thisvalue +'').show();
```

Or within 1 selector

```
$('#detailsDiv > table.' +thisvalue).show();
```

`hasClass` checks if the table has a class, which returns a boolean. The `filter` function filters between te current results.

Live demo: http://jsfiddle.net/78UKh/4/

Comment: Thanks a lot. sometime we miss a bit ;)

Answer (score 1):

Try it this way:

```
$('#detailsTab th').live('click', function(){
            var thisvalue = $(this).attr('id');
            $('table.' + thisvalue).show();
});
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/78UKh/7/).

Since I assume that you want to show only the relevant `table`:

```
$('#detailsTab th').live('click', function(){
            var thisvalue = $(this).attr('id');
            $('table').not('#detailsTab, table.' + thisvalue).hide();
            $('table.' + thisvalue).show();
});
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/78UKh/11/).

**Note**: in your [JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/78UKh/4/) the `id` for your 'Amenities' `th` was 'amenities' whereas the class-name for the relevant `table` was 'Amenities.' I've amended this so that they're both the same case in my demos.

Comment: How to hide other tables meanwhile??

Comment: you save my day. :)  i want to ask one more thing why you use `#detailsTab` in `$('table').not('#detailsTab, table.' + thisvalue).hide();`  whereas both tables are different

Comment: Because I wanted to ensure that line of jQuery would hide all tables except the header and the table you're trying to show. Effectively it'd still work with just `.not('#detailsTab')`, since the next line shows the relevant table anyway.

Answer (score 1):

http://jsfiddle.net/Microfed/78UKh/10/

Answer (score 0):

another selector you could use (better for other attributes)

```
$('#detailsDiv > table[class~="'+thisvalue+'"]').show();
```